# conda install python=3.9.0 has stopped or is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I had Python 3.7.4 before trying to use this to update to the latest version of python, but now it has been more than one hour since I ran the command and it still says that the kernel is busy.
Is it okay to restart the kernel and try again? What else can I do?

[image: The command]

Comment: Ever find a fix for this? Same thing is happening for me

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed anaconda already and want to update only python, it may not be possible because anaconda may restrict it. update the anaconda first with `conda update anaconda` then try to update the python with `conda update python`.

these commands should be run in anaconda prompt.